# Select rows that contain the first N unique values in a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, how do I select the rows that contain the first N=3 unique values in column X1?

Observe the first 3 unique values in column X1 are apple, car, and egg. How do I only select the rows that contain one of these values in column X1?

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------+
| X1      | X2                | X3      |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
| apple   | rob@hotmail.com   | 285     |
| apple   | geo@gmail.com     | 862     |
| car     | p6346@live.com    | 381     |
| egg     | simon@hotmail.com | -1058   |
| egg     | pierr@hotmail.com | 652     |
| egg     | j5@gmail.com      | 27      |
| grape   | peter@outlook.com | -1502   |
| grape   | ann@aol.com       | 621     |
| lime    | frank@gmail.com   | 501     |
| lime    | george@aol.com    | 314     |
| lime    | sam@gmail.com     | 615     |
| melon   | mike@hotmail.com  | 271     |
| melon   | jo@hotmail.com    | -97     |
| pear    | james@aol.com     | -97     |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

The desired result would be:

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------+
| X1      | X2                | X3      |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
| apple   | rob@hotmail.com   | 285     |
| apple   | geo@gmail.com     | 862     |
| car     | p6346@live.com    | 381     |
| egg     | simon@hotmail.com | -1058   |
| egg     | pierr@hotmail.com | 652     |
| egg     | j5@gmail.com      | 27      |
+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

Note X1 is ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Please avoid posting real emails in this type of public platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DENSE_RANK to achieve your required output as below-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=81288e4df6a557717bba41f87abb4681)

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 (
      SELECT *,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [X1]) RN
      FROM your_table
 )A
 WHERE RN <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived table for which you get the top 3 distinct `x1` and join it to the original table on matching `x1`s.

```
SELECT t.*
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    TOP (3)
                    ti.x1
                    FROM elbat ti
                    ORDER BY ti.x1) x
            INNER JOIN elbat t
                       ON t.x1 = x.x1;
```

Alternatively you can use the `dense_rank()` window function to assign a number to each record according to the order of its `x1`.

```
SELECT x.x1,
       x.x2,
       x.x3
       FROM (SELECT ti.x1,
                    ti.x2,
                    ti.x3,
                    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY ti.x1) rk
                    FROM elbat ti) x
       WHERE x.rk <= 3;
```